# How To Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Hello i was trying to modify an `object` form the values of another `object`

this is the one i need to modify :

```
  y = {name:'m' , age:'28' , g:{m:'n' , f:'y' , k:'n' ,
       other :{x:'f' , y:'m'}} , h:'6' , zip :'12345' } ;
```

the following object will loop in `object` `y` and if it found any matched element , it will change it's value to match object `x`

```
   ​x = {name :'y' , age:'17' , g :{m:'y' ,f:'n'}} ;
```

**CODE**

```
  for(var i in x){
     for(var o in y){
        if(i == o) y[o] = x[i] ; 
            }
      }
```

when this code runs it change the value of `y.(name and age )` it keeps `h and zip` values as it is which is great

**PROBLEM** is at `g` object it only change the value of `g.n` and `g.f`  and delete the rest of the `g object element`

**jsFiddle** [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9qkQ8/)

what i was hoping to get is

```
  y = {name:'y' , age:'17' , g:{m:'y' , f:'n' , k:'n' ,
   other :{x:'f' , y:'m'}} , h:'6' , zip :'12345' }
```

*i'm using jquery so if there is any jquery function that will help that's fine*

Comment: Hiya bruv, nice jsfiddle +1 for your question, now reading question !

Comment: Recursion. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: @SalmanA yes at the very bottom line i said i can use jquery ... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) with `deep` parameter:

> Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first
>   object.
>
> [...]
>
> The merge performed by $.extend() is not recursive by default; if a
>   property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be
>   completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second
>   object. The values are not merged. [...] However, by passing true for
>   the first function argument, objects will be recursively merged.
>   (Passing false for the first argument is not supported.)

```
var y = {
    name: 'm',
    age: '28',
    g: {
        m: 'n',
        f: 'y',
        k: 'n',
        other: {
            x: 'f',
            y: 'm'
        }
    },
    h: '6',
    zip: '12345'
};
var x = {
    name: 'y',
    age: '17',
    g: {
        m: 'y',
        f: 'n'
    }
};
$.extend(true, y, x);
console.log(y);
// {
//     "name": "y",
//     "age": "17",
//     "g": {
//         "m": "y",
//         "f": "n",
//         "k": "n",
//         "other": {
//             "x": "f",
//             "y": "m"
//         }
//     },
//     "h": "6",
//     "zip": "12345"
// }
```

Comment: well thanks this is working like magic ... but if you guys can explain to us why the above code didn't work this will be great

Comment: Your code does a one-level copy of properties; for example the `y.g` property is _completely_ overwritten by `x.g`. If you want to code the solution yourself, you must check if value of a property being assigned is an object (`typeof x[i] == "object"`); if so, copy properties of `x[i]` into `y[o]` one by one. Of course, you will then have to worry if `x[i].someProp` is it self an object :)

Answer (score 2):

the result is as expected, because you  are looping and comparing the properties of `x` and `y`, if the value is not equal you will replace the value of the property in `y` with the value of the property in `x`

and in this case `y.g == x.g` is false since there are different objects
so y.g will be replaced with x.g.

try this :

```
function compare(x, y) {

    for (var i in x) {
        for (var o in y) {
            if(typeof i == "object")
            {
                compare(i,o);
            }else{
                if (i == o) y[o] = x[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

compare(x,y);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9qkQ8/3/

Comment: The idea is right but the code needs an improvement: the properties of x that are not present in y should be copied to y as-is.

Answer (score 0):

| i'm using jquery so if there is any jquery function that will help that's fine

take a look at [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

```
$.extend(true, y, x);
```